# The result appeared to be 0.00001 instead of the value I assigned. Why?

Tags: c

Down here is a part of my current code (still incomplete). I was trying to assign the amount of cost to *costPtr. But after assigning it, I test the result in the main function to see if I got the right value for my choice, the result appeared to be 0.00001 instead of the value as assigned (299.9 or 349.99 or 999.99). What's wrong? I couldn't find the answer.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void DisplayApps(char *selectionPtr);
void SetCost(char selection, double *costPtr);
//void PaymentOptions(double *depositPtr, double cost);
//int Compare(double deposit, double choiceCost);
//void Pay(double *depositPtr, double choiceCost);
//void GetChanged(double *depositPtr, double choiceCost);
//void DoItAgain(char *quitPtr);

int main()
{
    char selection;
    char *selectionPtr;
    //double choiceCost;
    double *costPtr;
    //double *depositPtr;
    //char *quitPtr;

    printf("Welcome to the App Store\n");
    printf("***************************\n\n");
    DisplayApps(&selectionPtr);
    selection = selectionPtr;
    printf("Your choice %c\n", selection);
    SetCost(selection, &costPtr);
    printf("The cost of this item is %fl\n", costPtr);

    return 0;
}

void DisplayApps(char *selectionPtr)
{
    printf("-------------------------\n");
    printf("HERE ARE THE SLECTIONS\n");
    printf("C -- Clown Punching             $299.99\n");
    printf("V -- Virtual Snow Globe         $349.99\n");
    printf("R -- Remote PC                  $999.99\n");
    printf("G -- Grocery List Helper        $2.99\n");
    printf("M -- Mobile Cam Viewer          $89.99\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter a selection: ", *selectionPtr);
    scanf(" %c", &*selectionPtr);

}

void SetCost(char selection, double *costPtr)
{
    double c = 299.99;
    double v = 349.99;
    double r = 999.99;
    double g = 2.99;
    double m = 89.99;
    if (selection == "C" || selection == "c")
    {
        *costPtr = c;
    }
    else if (selection == "V" || selection == "v")
    {
        *costPtr = v;
    }
    else if (selection == "R" || selection == "r")
    {
        *costPtr = r;
    }
    else if (selection == "G" || selection == "g")
    {
        *costPtr = g;
    }
    else if (selection == "M" || selection == "m")
    {
        *costPtr = m;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code, I can almost certainly conclude that this is a *floating point issue.*  See [Why are floating point numbers inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: Welcome to the joys of floating point inaccuracy.  It's going to bug the rest of your working life if you become a developer.  Here's something to read:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Replacing your code with one of those would make confirming that Robert Harvey is almost certainly right much faster.

Comment: The `double` type is incapable of representing the number 2.99, instead, you get something closer to 2.9900000000000002131628207.  The same is true for the other decimals.  (The computer is binary.)

Comment: *"the result appeared to be 0.00001 instead of the value as assigned (299.9 or 349.99 or 999.99)"* – dang, that's a *really* big floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I'm trying to read it right now. This may help me somehow.

Comment: There are several layers of bugs in this code - fixing one only reveals more problems...

Comment: I mean, uninitialized pointers, pointer type mismatch etc. This code should crash, but is too buggy to do so;) Turn on compiler warnings and read them.

Comment: "result appeared to be 0.00001"  --> Not possible for output to be `"0.00001"`. Post the _exact_ textual output of `printf("The cost of this item is %fl\n", costPtr);`  Hint: Are you getting `"0.000000l"`?  Look closely at the format.

Comment: I started from the scratch and made it worked. Thanks everyone for suggestion and help :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's why a reasonable person looks at the question rather than just the title.

Comment: I asked my teacher and she pointed out that it was because I wrote "C" instead of 'C'...
I fixed it and it worked ^^!

Answer (score 2):

Your program, is malformed and with Undefined Behaviour, because you are calling to to `SetCost` with a `double**` on a `double*` argument.

You should better declare the `cost` variable as a normal `double` in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    // ...
    double cost;
    // ...
    SetCost(selection, &cost);
    printf("The cost of this item is %fl\n", cost);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, yet it crashed, unfortunately.

Comment: @user6866732 Edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, declare `double cost` and pass `&cost` to `SetCost`. Then print `cost`. There are problems here that your compiler could have caught if warnings were enabled. For example, you're passing a `double **` to `SetCost` when it's looking for a `double *`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)